# Updated component based on state from other component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a hamburger component that has no className prop, only color, and using the ternary operator its color changes only after page reload, but for example FontAwesomeIcon using dark:text-gray-50 changes its color.

This is my TodoHeader.jsx component

```
import Search from "./Search";
import Switcher from "../Switcher";
import {faBars} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {Fade as Hamburger} from "hamburger-react";
import {useProSidebar} from "react-pro-sidebar";
import useDarkSide from "../../hooks/useDarkSide";


const TodoHeader = () => {
    const {collapseSidebar} = useProSidebar();
    const [colorTheme, setTheme] = useDarkSide();

    const toggle = () => {
        collapseSidebar()
    }

    return (
        <div className={"flex items-center justify-between border-b-2 dark:border-gray-600"}>
            <div className={"flex items-center ml-8"}>
                <Hamburger direction={"right"} onToggle={toggle} color={ colorTheme === 'light' ? "#f3f4f6" : "#1f2937"}/>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} onClick={toggle} className={"text-center dark:text-gray-50"}/>
                <h1 className={"p-4 text-2xl text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-100"}>Todo List</h1>
            </div>
            <Search/>
            <Switcher/>
        </div>
    );
};
export default TodoHeader;
```

This is my customhook

```
import {useEffect, useMemo, useState} from "react";

const useDarkSide = () => {
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState(localStorage.theme);
    const colorTheme = theme === "dark" ? "light" : "dark";

    useEffect(() => {
        const root = window.document.documentElement;
        root.classList.remove(colorTheme);
        root.classList.add(theme);
        localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);
    }, [theme, colorTheme]);

    return [colorTheme, setTheme]
}
export default useDarkSide
```

And this is Switcher.jsx component that handles dark/light mode changes

```
import {useState} from "react";
import { DarkModeSwitch} from "react-toggle-dark-mode";
import useDarkSide from "../hooks/useDarkSide";

const Switcher = () => {
    const [colorTheme, setTheme] = useDarkSide();
    const [darkSide, setDarkSide] = useState(
        colorTheme === "light" ? true : false
    );

    const toggleDarkMode = (checked) => {
        setTheme(colorTheme);
        setDarkSide(checked);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <DarkModeSwitch
                style={{ marginRight: '2rem' }}
                checked={darkSide}
                onChange={toggleDarkMode}
                size={30}
            />
        </>
    );
}
export default Switcher
```

I think the problem is that when I use the useDarkSide hook on the header it doesn't render the header component, but I don't know how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was with me trying to access theme state that was inside switcher component through useDarkSide custom hook, but it's create another separated state. So the solution was using global state, in my case i used redux.